# how can a windows service control another program?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, service

I have a program, and in that program i can set the user's privileges (called the User Access Manager) i.e. set the user lever, change their settings etc.. I want this program to run as a service and be able to access it either locally or remotely. I would then have another program (a UI) which would connect to the service and allow them to control the User Access Management

my question is what is the best way to achieve this? and how can i access part of the program (the User Access Manager) from another computer?

////// **edit** ///////
i want the service to control only a part of another program not the whole program. e.g. i want the service to only run visual studios properties not run the whole program..

Comment: Try WCF. RPC is easy with WCF.

Comment: i actually have the service already created using a Win32 console application but it doesn't do anything right now

Comment: You have to make your service hosting a WCF Service manually and reference it in your client program. [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms734712.aspx).

Comment: i am using code from here for the service: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948

Comment: The code you provided is creating a program running as a Windows service. It can't be used for communicating between PCs. Which you will need WCF or other libraries. If you don't like to interop with .Net, you need to find a RPC library(MS has one also) or using MSMQ or developing a customized service yourself.

Comment: i have never used WCF that's why i'm using windows service in c++

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28364/discussion-between-iamsleepy-and-lisa-collins)